# 'WSM-00081 : The X.509 certificate is not signed' while signing with jmeter web security plugins

Tags: jmeter, x509, jmeter-plugins, ws-security, jmeter-3.2

I've got service to load test which uses WS security to authenticate requests. I've followed the steps mentioned here - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-soap-ws-security-load-tests-in-jmeter but my server under test failed with below error.

Jmeter Version: 3.2 r1790749

My configurations:

Request:

```
 <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa05="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="true"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-c0365a42-c4e4-49e1-94ce-6da57c4d8b60">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-91db268d-ad9c-4279-b2b7-5b2a2f274c81"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus soapenv wsa05"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-128"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus soapenv"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>8c1zFU59JNzfJ3AbXTxn+jC46ZU=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-129"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus soapenv"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>6WpWJAk7NdlgtPH6LzKvcHV2S1s=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-130"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus soapenv"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>BVLT6+H8s/VW+D1olbM3yQrRI+Q=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-131"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus soapenv"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>vc7yU0o3VGsjI8iIJIQTH5vA1A4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-d6f07fd3-1b3a-4c55-a668-f8d2464c6dd8"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>lBydSuIFHgWDOLds34mVNmHC//4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#TS-ee20684a-6b4c-4207-a67a-9245f0c3e19f"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus soapenv wsa05 wsse"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>nFiaKa8fMrSxHLhKL8B2BV2ujjU=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#Timestamp-69"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus soapenv wsa05 wsse"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>cJD//Tj+XcnZfn0tG1NMRISS45M=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-dd30423a-5490-498f-b2de-2dbe34c1d1e8"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="jus soapenv wsa05"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>obSOseNPR/F9wWfpxucQ+oHyXKc=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>NdtPrzlN/aExQhiklnPWR2ZmfgokKQ5e46Xor2LhYNB/o4vs5GfBb2zM87IsincbWYlbu8ggGSiZ1cMRz+Sj2ssovB5cKO+FzLkF0TaCIYqtbf434n+xlrDowhfh21vDICY0dl8uLGqU6MoznZDpLYQ10q6gM0grDbTmMbl++TE=</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-7684c7f7-1cba-4f7a-b684-21459c4b937a"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-34ab6a5b-28dc-4cfc-9773-bc4e94a0bffe" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-c0365a42-c4e4-49e1-94ce-6da57c4d8b60" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-ee20684a-6b4c-4207-a67a-9245f0c3e19f"><wsu:Created>2019-02-21T03:54:08.894Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2019-02-21T20:34:08.894Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp>
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-69" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2019-02-21T03:02:11.297Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2019-02-25T19:42:11.297Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
  </wsse:Security>
  <wsa05:To xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-129">REMOVED</wsa05:To>
  <wsa05:Action xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-131">REMOVED</wsa05:Action>
  <wsa05:From xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-128">
     <wsa05:Address>PoliceNIA</wsa05:Address>
  </wsa05:From>
  <wsa:ReplyTo xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-dd30423a-5490-498f-b2de-2dbe34c1d1e8">
     <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
  </wsa:ReplyTo>
  <wsa05:MessageID xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-130">001</wsa05:MessageID>
```

[Jmeter Message Signer configurations Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKU69.png)

[Update Jmeter Message Signer with Binary Security Token to sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEmy8.png)

Server Error:

> --- Error message:
>    oracle.wsm.security.SecurityException: WSM-00081 : The X.509 certificate is not signed.
>           at oracle.wsm.security.policy.scenario.processor.Wss10X509TokenProcessor.verify(Wss10X509TokenProcessor.java:415)
>           at oracle.wsm.security.policy.scenario.executor.Wss10MutualAuthWithCertsScenarioExecutor.receiveRequest(Wss10MutualAuthWithCertsScenarioExecutor.java:147)
>           at oracle.wsm.security.policy.scenario.executor.SecurityScenarioExecutor.execute(SecurityScenarioExecutor.java:662)
>           at oracle.wsm.policyengine.impl.runtime.AssertionExecutor.execute(AssertionExecutor.java:44)
>           at oracle.wsm.policyengine.impl.runtime.WSPolicyRuntimeExecutor.executeSimpleAssertion(WSPolicyRuntimeExecutor.java:526)
>           at oracle.wsm.policyengine.impl.runtime.WSPolicyRuntimeExecutor.executeAndAssertion(WSPolicyRuntimeExecutor.java:438)
>           at oracle.wsm.policyengine.impl.runtime.WSPolicyRuntimeExecutor.execute(WSPolicyRuntimeExecutor.java:385)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a limitation in plugin version1.6. Snapshot 1.7 version has been released to fix this issue. Thanks to the author for fixing this in no time.

Updated Snapshot can be downloaded from there - https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity/releases/tag/1.7-SNAPSHOT

Issue logged in Github - https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you misconfigured the [SOAP Message Signer](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity#soap-message-signer) as I fail to see the relevant entries in your SOAP payload, please double check the PreProcessor's configuration (keystore type and location, password, etc.)

Also these lines look suspicious as now it's 2019:

```
<wsu:Created>2015-02-25T03:02:11.297Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2015-02-25T19:42:11.297Z</wsu:Expires>
```

And last but not the least, according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) you should always be using the latest JMeter version so consider updating your JMeter 3.2 (which is 2 years old) to the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T for your quick response. Further investigation suggests me that, in Parts to Sign section I am missing the xml tag for X509 certificate. I've updated Parts to Sign section and added value for BinarySecurityToken but Jmeter still not signing the request. Please have a look at the attached screendump and raw request.

Comment: I can see all the other ws elements are getting signed but not the certificate. There muse be configurations issue which I may have missed. Any help would be appreciated.  Setup I've got is, Http Sampler -> SOAP Message Timestamp -> Soap Message Signer